# Connection refused when I calling a url for web-services

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call a url for web-services. But when I am calling it, getting the asynchronous suspension and 
 Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused.

```
Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  final response = await http.get('http://localhost:8069/test');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print ("122121");
      print (response.body);
      return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }
}



E/flutter (19112): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19112): #5      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (19112): #6      fetchPost (package:flutter_app/main.dart:67:26)
E/flutter (19112): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Error:

```
E/flutter (19112): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection
refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 51382
E/flutter (19112): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: `<asynchronous suspension>` is not an error. It indicates that the next function in the stacktrace did not call the previous one synchronously but asynchronously. What is the error?

Comment: Are you running the web service locally on port 8069? Can you get the page from within the browser? Connection refused sound like you are not running it...

Comment: @SebastianK Yes i am getting the results in local browser

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and replaced 'localhost' in the URL with my local machine's actual IP address because I read that the emulator can't link up to 'localhost' directly.

To find my IP address, I went to my computer's wifi settings, selected the network I was connected to, clicked properties, and then looked for "IPv4 address".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).